# Multiplication of two small numbers with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In some point of my project i have to multiply two small float like 8.696503446228892e-159 and 1.2425389522444519e-158 as i test in following code:

```
def a2(a,b):
  a = tf.cast(a, tf.float64)
  b = tf.cast(b, tf.float64)
  d = a*b
  return d
```

it will return 0 which cause lots of problem (because it is used in my loss function) any solution how can i multiply them?

Comment: What is it that you are optimising that you are unable to take a fraction `e-300` as a zero?

Comment: @BishwarupBhattacharjee this is a term i used to calculate bhattacharya distance the actual code is tf.log(tf.linalg.det(temp_sigma) /                                                                              (tf.sqrt(tf.linalg.det(sigma1) *                                                                                       tf.linalg.det(sigma2)))) where the det of sigma1 and sigma2 are assumed as a and b so if i take the multiplication as zero it cause inf loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling large discrepancies in computational magnitude is a field of study in itself.
The first-order way to do this is to write your evaluation code to detect the situation and re-order the operations so as to preserve significant bits of each result.  For instance, let's simplify your names a bit:

```
tf.log(tf.linalg.det(temp_sigma) /
   (tf.sqrt(tf.linalg.det(sigma1) * tf.linalg.det(sigma2))))
```

turns into

```
log(det(A) / (sqrt(det(B) * det(c))))
```

The case you have is that `det(B)` and `det(C)` are barely above zero, but relatively near each other: the result of `sqrt(det(B) * det(C))` will be close to either determinant.

Change the order of operations.  For this instance, distribute the square root and do the divisions individually:

```
log(
    ( det(A) / sqrt(det(B)) ) / sqrt(det(C)) )
```

Does that get you moving along?